# mongodb search if field name contains ('something')

Tags: mongodb, where-clause

Since Mongo is schema-less, it is known that documents can have different keys.

I am in a situation that I need to search on the field name [i.e key name] not its value.

I read about it on many places and found that it could be possible using `$where` 
and I realize that is not efficient; but that is ok! because it will be one time investigation before production.

So I tried to build the query but I failed to generate expected result, since I know that the key is available in the database.

my JS code:

```
function kName(){
   for (var k in obj){
       if (k.startsWith('gold')){
           return obj
         }
   }
}
```

so I used it as the following:

```
db.nodes.find({$where: kName})
```

but I failed to return valid result because I know there is a 'gold' field name

then I tried:

```
db.nodes.find({$where: kName()})
```

again failed.

then I modified the function:

```
function kName(obj){
   for (var k in obj){
       if(k.startsWith('gold')){
           return obj
         }
   }
}
```

and again I tried
    db.nodes.find({$where: kName()})
and failed.

then tried

```
db.nodes.find({$where: kName(obj)})
```

So my question is:

how can i use my own JS function to utilize the $where clause in Mongodb to find that a field name exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try with $exists:

```
db.nodes.find({kName:{$exists: true}})
```

It returns all documents containing specified key or property. See MongoDb documentation for [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#exists)

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#exists `$exists` doesn't support field name. it only search if the document exists or not. I tried your suggestion and failed to get expected result . Thank you for your reply

Comment: I'm not sure how you got impression that it doesn't check if fields exists or not. See what document says **When boolean is true, $exists matches the documents that contain the field**

Comment: Yes @Saleem. `$exists` can work when you are looking for a field in the document. my case is that `kName` is JS function (not key name) that should check every field name if it starts with ("string here").. So my opinion is that `$exists` doesn't work with JS function but with fields (keys) of the document. Also i tried it with no success. please correct me if I am missing something .. again thank you for your valuable time